# Crash specialized String.imageSize(),

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a crash in this extension method of `String`:

```
    func imageSize() -> CGSize {
//        self = "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/mimg.haraj.com.sa/userfiles30/2018-8-6/524x334-1_-E7VSb5T20mOouX.jpg"

        var width = 0
        var height = 0

        let split0 = self.split(separator: "/")
        if split0.count > 0 {
            let split1 = split0.last?.split(separator: "-")
            if (split1?.count)! > 0 {

                let split2 = split1?.first?.decomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping.split(separator: "x")

                width = (split2?.first?.decomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping.toInt())!

                if (split2?.count)! > 1 {
//                    let split2 = split1![1].decomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping.split(separator: "-")
                    height = (split2?.last?.decomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping.toInt())!
                }
            }
        }

        return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
    }
```

The crash is on line `return CGSize(width: width, height: height)`

I have created an `NSString` version like this to use the same above method:

```
@objc extension NSString {
    func imageSize1() -> CGSize {
        return (self as String).imageSize()
    }
}
```

This is then called from obj-c code:

```
CGSize imageSize = [url imageSize1];
```

Examples of url are:

https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/mimg.haraj.com.sa/userfiles30/2019-02-07/675x900-1_-CdC62Y2hcV7208.jpg

https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/mimg.haraj.com.sa/userfiles30/2019-02-07/675x900-1_-697e3no8ec2E1I.jpg

https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/mimg.haraj.com.sa/userfiles30/2019-02-07/675x900-1_-8Af5D20wh9b62z.jpg

What this `imageSize()` method does is that it parses the image size from the url. The urls above contain the sizes 675x900 -> widthxheight.

In rare case we encounter a url where there is no information of the size and the url is not in the format above. So if the size is not found `CGSize = (0 , 0)` is returned.

I have tested this method on all expected scenarios.
But due to some reasons the method is causing crashes. May be I missed/messed something.

Here is the link to Crashlytics [issue](http://crashes.to/s/def0dae1fb5).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try don't use force unwrap `!`

```
let exampleString1 = "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/mimg.haraj.com.sa/userfiles30/2018-8-6/524x334-1_-E7VSb5T20mOouX.jpg"
let exampleString2 = "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/mimg.haraj.com.sa/userfiles30/2019-02-07/675x900-1_-697e3no8ec2E1I.jpg"
let exampleString3 = "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/mimg.haraj.com.sa/userfiles30/2019-02-07/675x900-1_-CdC62Y2hcV7208.jpg"

extension String {
    func imageSize() -> CGSize? {
        // last url component
        guard let imageName = self.split(separator: "/").last else { return nil }
        guard let imageSizeString = imageName.split(separator: "-").first else { return nil }
        let sizes = imageSizeString.split(separator: "x")
        guard let first = sizes.first,
            let last = sizes.last,
            let wight = Int(String(first)),
            let height = Int(String(last))
        else { return nil }

        return CGSize(width: wight, height: height)
    }
}

exampleString1.imageSize() // Optional((524.0, 334.0))
exampleString2.imageSize() // Optional((675.0, 900.0))
exampleString3.imageSize() // Optional((675.0, 900.0))
```

Also try to use guard let and return nil if something wrong. For example Url schema can be changed

Answer (score 1):

The crash is most likely due to force unwrapping optionals. There are several cases in your code where you're using it, which will lead to a runtime error if file name in your URL has a different format than you expect. Try

```
func imageSize() -> CGSize {
    // self = "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/mimg.haraj.com.sa/userfiles30/2018-8-6/524x334-1_-E7VSb5T20mOouX.jpg"

    var width = 0
    var height = 0

    let split0 = self.split(separator: "/")
    if let split1 = split0.last?.split(separator: "-")
    {
        if let split2 = split1.first?.decomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping.split(separator: "x")
        {
            width = (split2.first?.decomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping.toInt()) ?? 0
            if split2.count > 1 {
                height = (split2.last?.decomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping.toInt()) ?? 0
            }
        }
    }

    return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
}
```

Comment: Your code is giving me error : "Cannot use optional chaining on non-optional value of type '[String.SubSequence]' (aka 'Array<Substring>')"

Comment: on the line "height = (split2?.last?.decomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping.toInt()) ?? 0"